# For each class create a scatter plot between two lists

Tags: python, list, pandas-groupby, data-analysis, scatter-plot

I read a CSV file and I created the two following lists.
For each class, I wish to create a scatter plot between values2 and values3. I wanna see the correlation between values2 and values3 for each class. Is this possible?

```
List1=vehiclesData.groupby('Class')['values2'].apply(list)
List2=vehiclesData.groupby('Class')['values3'].apply(list)
```

If you print List1, it will look like this:

```
Compact Cars                          [2.2, 1.8, 1.8...
Large Cars                            [3.8, 3.8, 3.8...
Midsize Cars                          [2.8, 2.8, 4.0...
Midsize Station Wagons                [3.0, 3.0, 2.3...
```

If you print List2, it will look like this:

```
Compact Cars                          [19, 22, 25...
Large Cars                            [20, 18, 20...
Midsize Cars                          [19, 19, 16...
Midsize Station Wagons                [19, 18, 21...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three popular correlation measures ― Pearson, Spearman and Kendall Tau correlations.  Scatter plot between two variables also helps to understand correlation visually.  Following code will help you to compute all three types of correlation for each '*class*' and create class-wise scatter plots between '*values2*' and '*values3*'.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import pearsonr, spearmanr, kendalltau

df = ... # pandas data frame containing the original data

# unique classes
classes = list(set(list(df.loc[:, "Class"])))

# creating space for making plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols = len(classes), figsize = (len(classes)*5, 4.5), dpi = 120)

# Table that holds class-wise correlation values
correlation_table = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Class", "Pearson correlation",
                                            "Spearman correlation", "Kendall Tau correlation"])

# populate class-wise correlation values and create class-wise scatter plots
for i, c in enumerate(classes):

    # filter dataset by class
    sub_df = df[df["Class"]==c]

    # Pearson correlation
    p_c, _ = pearsonr(sub_df.loc[:, "values2"], sub_df.loc[:, "values3"])
    # Spearman correlation
    s_c, _ = spearmanr(sub_df.loc[:, "values2"], sub_df.loc[:, "values3"])
    # Kendall Tau correlation
    k_c, _ = kendalltau(sub_df.loc[:, "values2"], sub_df.loc[:, "values3"])
    # populate correlation values
    correlation_table = correlation_table.append({"Class": c,
                                                  "Pearson correlation": p_c,
                                                  "Spearman correlation": s_c,
                                                  "Kendall Tau correlation": k_c},
                                                 ignore_index = True)
    
    # Create scatter plot
    ax[i].scatter(sub_df.loc[:, "values2"], sub_df.loc[:, "values3"])
    ax[i].set_title(f"Class: {c}")
    ax[i].set_xlabel("values2")
    ax[i].set_ylabel("values3")

print(correlation_table)
fig.show()
```